# Jenkins build failure due to closed channel Exception

Tags: jenkins, networking, jenkins-plugins, docker-machine, jenkins-agent

Jenkins version -2.76
Slave jar version -3.11
Master is running on Linux
And slave is running on docker container inside the windows machine

Whenever I triggered a job for more than 3hours it was failed with the closed channel Exception. At first it was failed less than 30 min. After changing some registry parameters now it extended upto 2 hours. But now I want it for more than 3hours